# SQLite query problem, and atomicity of transactions

Tags: sql, sqlite, atomic

Problem: I have two tables (`members1` and `members2`) which are just lists of usernames. I need to change a username in `members1`, but only if the new username does not already appear in either table (in other words, the usernames must be unique across both tables).

SQL is outside my comfort zone, but after a couple of hours of Googling I've come up with the query below. I'm actually using SQLite's C API, so this is just a test shell script to check the syntax. The script changes an old name to a new name, where `$1` is the old name, and `$2` is the new name:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sqlite3 test.db <<EOF

update members1 set uname=
  case 
    exists(select 1 from members1 where uname='$2') or
    exists(select 1 from members2 where uname='$2')
  when 1 then '$1'
  else '$2'
  end
where uname='$1';

EOF
```

Questions:

1. this seems to work, but does it make sense? It seems very long-winded. Is there a better way to do this? In particular, if there is a name conflict, is it actually necessary to update `members1` to change the old name back to itself?
2. How safe is this if multiple processes are doing the same thing at the same time? Is it possible for process A to change 'john' to 'jim', and process B to simultaneously change 'jo' to 'jim', so that 'jim' appears twice in the database?
3. What actually is the protocol for upper/lower-case? The code above runs without problems, but everything on the web is upper-case.

Thanks.

Comment: Store the user names in a single table with a primary key to access them from other tables!  Then you can guarantee uniqueness with a minimum of fuss.  You can have other columns in separate tables, if that is necessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Unfortunately, in real life, the databases are more complex and already have unrelated primary keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you. I made a unique 'umembers' table.

I filled it with triggers. (members1 and members2 too) You can figure out the update trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS members1trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON members1 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO umembers VALUES(new.uname, other properties);
END;
```

Then your update is soo

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sqlite3 test.db <<EOF

update members1 set uname=$2
where uname='$1' and not exists (select 1 from umembers where uname= $2);

EOF
```

2. Of course you should create unique constraint on umembers.
   And if there are paralell update then second perhaps can throw exception.
   But I think index locks it, and can't happen.
3. Security says use case insensitive logins.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/241701/case-sensitive-logins